# How to retrieve license information with nuget command after version 3.3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve license information with the available nuget commands. The command ***Get-package | Select-Object Id, LicenseUrl*** does not work anymore and the ***Open-PackagePage*** command is deprecated and will be removed in the next release. Does anyone know what to use instead after nuget version 3.3?

Comment: What do you mean by "`Get-Package | Select-Object Id, LicenseUrl` does not work"? What is the exact error you are seeing?

Comment: The license url has been added back in NuGet 3.4. There is a [github issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1416) open on NuGet for this.

Comment: No error, but the LicenseUrl object is empty :)

Answer (score 0):

The license url has been added back in NuGet 3.4.

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1416) open on NuGet for this.

Currently NuGet 3.4 is not yet released. There is an [RC release](http://dist.nuget.org/index.html) which you could try or you can wait for the official final release.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Matt!